# SEO and Handling Temporary Content

Tags: url, seo, http-headers, http-status-code-404

If you have time limited content, for example, pages for events or classified items, which expire once the event has past or the item has been sold, or just after a fixed period, what is the best way to handle that in terms of SEO and being friendly to the Google Bot?

So at the moment my temporary URLs fire a 404 once they have expired. I would like them to be indexed. But how does google feel about temporary URLs that expire and become 404?

What is the best practice here? I am thinking that expiring to 404 probably isn't it! An alternative would be to keep the page and content, but mark it as expired, similar to how Ebay handles expired auctions. However, I see that as inefficient. Of course once a URL expires, the item and link are no longer listed on the site, so perhaps search engines will drop it at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never expire or delist a URL.

Instead, why not repurpose that URL?

If you're serving up ecommerce content, such as a product listing, push the content further to the bottom of the page and, like eBay, serve up a product cross-sell immediately above it.

Per your example, it would be ideal to keep the original content on the page for an event. And simultaneously (so not as to degrade your visitor's experience by display outdated content) show SIMILAR EVENTS that they might be interested in. Or SIMILAR CLASSIFIED ADS.

Comment: Thanks. I have taken your advice and rather than delete items and show a 404 I now keep the item page, but delete some assets such as full size images (keep the thumbs, content etc only) and put a "similar items" block above and state that the content below is out of date/expired etc. Links to the page also roll off the listings so are no longer listed on the site once expired. Although my original question could be open to opinion, I think your answer is a good answer, and an opinion which makes sense and has been implemented to make a difference to the application. So thanks :)

Comment: Great! Check on that "expired content" a few months after it expires and always make sure it features that dynamic "similar items" block, as well as plenty of links to active, updated pages.